# CMake change files and folder permissions

Tags: windows, cmake, wix, file-permissions, cpack

I have a CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(MyProject VERSION 1.0.0)

install(DIRECTORY images
  DESTINATION "."
  DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS WORLD_READ WORLD_WRITE
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.png")

install(FILES file.json DESTINATION "."
    PERMISSIONS WORLD_READ WORLD_WRITE)

include(CPack)
```

Next, I use CPack and Wix to create an MSI installer.
The package is installed into C:\Program Files\MyProject
The package is installed by the Windows Service.
I want to set writing permissions for the Users group.
I added WORLD_WRITE permissions expecting that writing permissions for the Users group would be granted but adding WORLD_WRITE did not change permissions.
How can I add writing permission to the Users group?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `PERMISSIONS GROUP_WRITE` like in the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/command/install.html)